# Grabbing specific content

Tags: content, recent-posts

Right now I'm doing this (pseudo code)

```
posts = content_type("special_stuff");
$i = 0;
$n = 5;
$while(have_posts) {
    if($i == $n) {
        // print the content
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

This is what I'm doing to always get the `n`th item. I'm sure there is a better way, but I'm kind of a WP noob.

Related:

1. (this question) How do I grab the nth element of a content type? eg. always getting the 1st or 5th most recent element from the db.
2. List item

How do I do #1 based on content id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all learn [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class.

Answering on questions:

> (this question) How do I grab the nth element of a content type? eg. always getting the 1st or 5th most recent element from the db.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=special_stuff&posts_per_page=1&paged=5' );
```

> List item

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this, my first thought is to do:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'paged' => 5, 
    'post_type' => '[your_content_type]',
    ));
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
// loop stuff
endwhile;
```

Comment: What is the difference with my answer? Why do you repost my answer?

Comment: we were typing at the same time..?

Comment: looks like ....

Comment: I'm a sucker for whoever answers first (sorry jess). However, I like that you did more than a copy/paste for your answer so you get a +1